# I'm getting an TCL error in jupyter notebook while creating a button for dice simulator

Tags: tkinter, jupyter-notebook, tcl

```
import random 

# Creating a window 
window = Tk() 

# Setting background colour of the window 
window.configure(bg="black") 

# Setting geometry of the window 
window.geometry("550x350") 

# Setting title of the window 
window.title("Rolling The Dices Game") 

# Preventing maximizing of the window 
window.resizable(0, 0) 

window.mainloop() 
roll_button = Button(window, text="Roll!", 
                     width=10, height=2, 
                     font=15, bg="aqua", bd=2)]
```

What's wrong here

I was trying to create a button using tkinter library for dice simulator and ended up with the error

Comment: Please include the actual error in the body of your question. I'm guessing it's because you create the button after the call to `window.mainloop()`. That function doesn't return until the root window has been destroyed. After that you can no longer add widgets to it.

Comment: Either that or the notebook is running in an environment where it can't talk to a display server.